# How can I use a storage variable in one pallet as a configuration variable in another?

Tags: substrate

So you have 2 pallets. The goal is to have a configuration variable C in pallet_1:

- In pallet_2 have some logic that constantly changes storage var A;
- Then the runtime should automatically write the new state of var A
  to the constant C in pallet_1.

The configuration variable in pallet_1's trait should be something like `MyConfig: Get<u32>`

Something like this: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/recovery/src/lib.rs#L200

So this says that we need to define a type which implements the `Get<T>` trait:

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/support/src/traits.rs#L471

So this is just a function `fn get() -> T`

Lets then assume you have pallet_2, where there is some storage item you want to control this config:

```
decl_storage!{
    MyStorage: u32;
}
```

In your runtime/src/lib.rs, you define something like:

```
struct StorageToConfig;
impl Get<u32> for StorageToConfig {
     fn get() -> u32 {
         return pallet_2::MyStorage::get();
    }
}
```

*How can you use this struct in your trait definition in pallet_1, and make sure the runtime automatically pushes (or pallet_1 pulls from the runtime) the MyStorage var in pallet_2?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example of how you would attach the value of a configuration trait to another pallet's storage item.

### Pallet 1

Here is `pallet_1` which has the storage item we want to use.

> NOTE: This storage is marked `pub` so it is accessible outside the pallet.

```rust
use frame_support::{decl_module, decl_storage};
use frame_system::ensure_signed;

pub trait Trait: frame_system::Trait {}

decl_storage! {
    trait Store for Module<T: Trait> as TemplateModule {
        pub MyStorage: u32;
    }
}

decl_module! {
    pub struct Module<T: Trait> for enum Call where origin: T::Origin {
        #[weight = 0]
        pub fn set_storage(origin, value: u32) {
            let _ = ensure_signed(origin)?;
            MyStorage::put(value);
        }
    }
}
```

### Pallet 2

Here is `pallet_2` which has a configuration trait that we want to populate with the storage item from `pallet_1`:

```rust
use frame_support::{decl_module, dispatch, traits::Get};
use frame_system::ensure_signed;

pub trait Trait: frame_system::Trait {
    type MyConfig: Get<u32>;
}

decl_module! {
    pub struct Module<T: Trait> for enum Call where origin: T::Origin {
        #[weight = 0]
        pub fn do_something(origin) -> dispatch::DispatchResult {
            let _ = ensure_signed(origin)?;

            let _my_config =  T::MyConfig::get();

            Ok(())
        }
    }
}
```

### Runtime Configuration

These two pallets are very straightforward and work separately. But if we want to connect them, we need to configure our runtime:

```rust
use frame_support::traits::Get;

impl pallet_1::Trait for Runtime {}

pub struct StorageToConfig;
impl Get<u32> for StorageToConfig {
     fn get() -> u32 {
         return pallet_1::MyStorage::get();
    }
}

impl pallet_2::Trait for Runtime {
    type MyConfig = StorageToConfig;
}

// We also update the `construct_runtime!`, but that is omitted for this example.
```

Here we have defined a struct `StorageToConfig` which implements the `Get<u32>` trait that is expected by `pallet_2`. This struct tells the runtime when `MyConfig::get()` is called, it should then call `pallet_1::MyStorage::get()` which reads into runtime storage and gets that value.

So now, every call to `T::MyConfig::get()` in `pallet_2` will be a storage read, and will get whatever value is set in `pallet_1`.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: what if in pallet 2 rather than having one `type MyConfig: Get<u32>;` I would have a collection, by using a map from pallet 1 (whereby MyStorage is now a map with u32 key, and u32 value)

Comment: You should define your own trait instead of `Get` which supports the API that you would like to the storage.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually as creating a trait impl the struct and then in the runtime pass the struct to the receiver (by using the trait), what I did to learn this is to look at all of the pallets that are already there and see how the pass information

for instance this trait in authorship
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/640dd1a0a44b6f28af1189f0293ab272ebc9d2eb/frame/authorship/src/lib.rs#L39

is implmented here
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/77819ad119f23a68b7478f3ac88e6c93a1677fc1/frame/aura/src/lib.rs#L148

and here it is composed (not with aura impl but session)

https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/549050b7f1740c90855e777daf3f9700750ad7ff/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L363

you should also read this [https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#:~:text=A%20trait%20tells%20the%20Rust,type%20that%20has%20certain%20behavior](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#:%7E:text=A%20trait%20tells%20the%20Rust,type%20that%20has%20certain%20behavior)

Comment: You have self-answered here, so the issue is resolved?

Comment: @ShawnTabrizi in the answer's example the original FindAuthor is in the frame_system trait so you can import it like any other system trait ( traits::{Get, FindAuthor} )
using pallets though, do I need to include pallet_2 as a dependency in the Cargo.toml of pallet_1, or will it be automatically in scope due to StorageToConfig being in the runtime?
Also, there's the secondary question of how to make sure the runtime automatically pushes (or pallet_1 pulls from the runtime) the MyStorage var in pallet_2?